# End of File Expected error in JSON file (VSCode)

Tags: json

I have a JSON file that is formatted like this:

```
{
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_index": "newsvit",
  "_source": {
    "content": "   \u0628\u0647 \u06af\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0634 \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u0627\u060c \u062a\u06cc\u0645 \u0647\u0627\u06cc \u062a\u0631\u0627\u06a9\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0633\u0627\u0632\u06cc ",
    "title": "\u0641\u06cc\u0646\u0627\u0644 \u062c\u0627\u0645 \u062d\u0630\u0641\u06cc\u061b \u0648\u062f\u0627\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0631\u0632 \u062d\u0627\u062c\u06cc \u067e\u0648\u063",

    "lead": "\u062a\u0647\u0631\u0627\u0646 - \u0627\u06cc\u0631\u0646\u0627 - \u062f\u06cc\u062f\u0627\u0631 \u067e\u0627\u06cc\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u062c\u0627\u0645 f.",
    "agency": "36",
    "date_created": 1494521741,
    "url": "http://www.irna.ir/fa/News/82525960/",
    "image": "uploads/2017/05/11/2561366787.jpg",
    "category": "5"
  },
  "_type": "news",
  "_id": "2981938"
}
{
...
```

but after one object ends, at the beginning of the new parenthesis I receive this error:

```
{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Asus/test.json",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#2",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "End of file expected.",
    "source": "json",
    "startLineNumber": 17,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 17,
    "endColumn": 2
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try using only one set of parentheses for the top level. And if you need more objects make it an array

```
{
  "objects": [{
     your object 1 properties
  }, {
     your object 2 properties
  }, {
     your object 3 properties
  }]
}
```

Comment: What you provided does not seem to be a valid json. Maybe you could provide a fiddle for what you try to accomplish. "A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names: false null true" -from https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-4 . So by putting two objects like that json can not qualify it as a valid JSON value

Comment: This answer solved this problem for me for the jsondecode(...) Matlab function. Thanks!